# Deserializing JSON to C# classes on WCF Rest Service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, null

I am trying to deserializing the JSON my rest service receives but one of the arguments is being null as the following image shows:

[image: debug shows null argument]

Here is the JSON that my service is receiving:

[image: JSON received on my rest service]

And here is the class declaration of the input of the service:

```
[DataContract]
public class OperationInput
{

    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ErrorData[] ErrorList { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ACTPRDX { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public PriceData PriceInfo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string RequestID { get; set; }

    public class ErrorData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }


    public class PriceData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string PriceDetail { get; set; }

    }

}

[DataContract]
public class OperationOutput
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
interface IRegisterOperation
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/registeroperation",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "*")]
    OperationOutput Operation(OperationInput input);
}
```

For the ErrorList argument it seems to be working although its different because it is an array of object and PriceData is just an object, I don't understand why is it showing null and can't parse the information I provided...

Comment: Your json has `PriceData` member. But your classes have `PriceInfo` member. Names are different.

Comment: Remove `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,` and Pass Json like `{"PriceInfo": {"Value": "10","PriceDetail": "zzz"} }`

Comment: The problem was PriceData member on JSON instead of PriceInfo, thanks, use that as an answer I will accept it ;)